# Ansible how to get the role name in dependent role

Tags: ansible

I have a role alice which depends on role bob:

File: roles/alice/meta/main.yml

```
dependencies:
- role: bob
```

In role bob, I need the role name of alice, but when I use {{ role_name }} below, the value of var_rolename is "bob" but not "alice". How can I retrieve the value "alice" in my use case?

```
dependencies:
- role: role_b
  vars: 
      var_rolename: "{{ role_name }}"
```

Comment: It's rather easy to say if there is only one role in the play. See my answer. But, you'll have to read the meta files on your own if there are more roles in a play. What is the use case? [edit] the question and make it [mre]. There might be a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cant thats not how ansible works. Lets imagine both `alice` and `adam` roles both have a dependency on role `bob`. Then `bob` will be run first but only once it wont run for both `alice` and `adam` you can read more about it here https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-role-dependencies

> Role dependencies are prerequisites, not true dependencies. The roles do not have a parent/child relationship. Ansible loads all listed roles, runs the roles listed under dependencies first, then runs the role that lists them. The play object is the parent of all roles, including roles called by a dependencies list.

> Ansible treats duplicate role dependencies like duplicate roles listed under roles:: Ansible only executes role dependencies once, even if defined multiple times, unless the parameters, tags, or when clause defined on the role are different for each definition. If two roles in a play both list a third role as a dependency, Ansible only runs that role dependency once, unless you pass different parameters, tags, when clause, or use allow_duplicates: true in the role you want to run multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Given the tree for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── roles
    ├── alice
    │   ├── meta
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    ├── bob
    │   └── tasks
    │       └── main.yml
    └── cloe
        ├── meta
        │   └── main.yml
        └── tasks
            └── main.yml

9 directories, 8 files
```

Both roles *alice* and *cloe* depend on the role *bob*

```yaml
shell> cat roles/alice/meta/main.yml 
dependencies:
  - role: bob
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/cloe/meta/main.yml 
dependencies:
  - role: bob
```

Create the same tasks for all roles and display the [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables):

- ansible_role_name: The fully qualified collection role name
- ansible_play_role_names: The names of the roles currently imported into the current play. This list does not contain the role names that are implicitly included through dependencies.
- ansible_role_names: The names of the roles currently imported into the current play, or roles referenced as dependencies of the roles imported into the current play.
- ansible_parent_role_paths: When the current role is being executed by means of an include_role or import_role action

```yaml
shell> cat roles/*/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    msg: |
      ansible_role_name: {{ ansible_role_name }}
      ansible_play_role_names: {{ ansible_play_role_names }}
      ansible_role_names: {{ ansible_role_names }}
      ansible_parent_role_names: {{ ansible_parent_role_names|d([]) }}
```

Create the playbook with the single role *alice*

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - alice
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [bob : debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_role_name: bob
    ansible_play_role_names: ['alice']
    ansible_role_names: ['bob', 'alice']
    ansible_parent_role_names: []

TASK [alice : debug] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_role_name: alice
    ansible_play_role_names: ['alice']
    ansible_role_names: ['bob', 'alice']
    ansible_parent_role_names: []
```

There is only one role in the list *ansible_play_role_names* that can depend on the role *bob*.

Create the playbook with both *alice* and *cloe*

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - alice
    - cloe
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [bob : debug] ****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_role_name: bob
    ansible_play_role_names: ['alice', 'cloe']
    ansible_role_names: ['cloe', 'alice', 'bob']
    ansible_parent_role_names: []

TASK [alice : debug] **************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_role_name: alice
    ansible_play_role_names: ['alice', 'cloe']
    ansible_role_names: ['cloe', 'alice', 'bob']
    ansible_parent_role_names: []

TASK [cloe : debug] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_role_name: cloe
    ansible_play_role_names: ['alice', 'cloe']
    ansible_role_names: ['cloe', 'alice', 'bob']
    ansible_parent_role_names: []
```

There are two roles in the list *ansible_play_role_names* that can depend on the role *bob*. Without reading the meta files you can't tell which one it is. If both roles depend on the role *bob* the question doesn't make sense because the role *bob* will be run only once.